# Text is not completely being displayed inside a div?

Tags: text, html

You can see everything in the picture (CSS, the behavior and divs).

The lower part of the p letter and g letter are hidden by the div.

http://img573.imageshack.us/img573/3553/screenshot3m.png

[image]

**EDIT:**

style.css:

```
/* Structure */
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}
#header, #intro, #tagline, #content {
    background: url(images/bg.png) top center repeat;
}
#branding, .content, .content-block, .posts, #footer a {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
#intro h2, #content h2, #nav li a {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
}
/* Header */
#header {
}
#header a {
    color: #333
}
#header a:hover {
    color: #28A
}
#branding {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    width: 940px;
}
#header h1, #lang {
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    width: 280px;
}
#header h1 {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 32px 0 10px;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
}
#nav li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
#lang {
    float: right;
}
#lang li {
    float: left;
}
#lang li a {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
/* Intro */
#intro, #intro2 {
    background: #333;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
#intro {
    height: 400px;
}
#intro2 {
    background: #333;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
#intro2 h2 {
    color: #DDD;
}

...
```

Comment: Forgive me, I missed the sentence explaining what was wrong. Do you have the CSS styles applied to the content class?

Comment: @Dan `.content { margin-left: 10px margin-right: 10px; }` Thats all.

Comment: You need to look at where in the chain going upwards, e.g. "content", "container", "intro2", is the height creating the bound.  You can't tell for sure from looking only at the style of "content".

Comment: @stoneMonkey77 Sorry, see the edit I added the CSS.

Comment: Thanks.  But that's not the whole css file, I don't think...?  What I was suggesting is just like you highlighted <h2 /> so you can see that that is not high enough for the content, try highlighting the enclosing div .content, and see whether it is already cut off there or at a higher level, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add css attribute line-height

```
.content h2{line-height: 35px;}
```